# spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and context:property-placeholder

Tags: spring

I have following bean declaration:

```
  <bean
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/classes/config/properties/database.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:config/properties/database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Now I want to change above PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to following format:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.config"/>
<util:properties id="jdbcProperties" 
           location="classpath:config/properties/database.properties"/>
```

1. ignoreResourceNotFound will ignore the property while running. e.g:
   When testing application WEB-INF/.. path will ignore( since maven
   project and property file is under src/main/resources/..), while
   launching web application, other property will ignore path, I need
   to implement same with above format.
2. should be able to add multiple property file like
   database.properties, test.properties etc.
3. in Spring 3, can I use annotation instead of these xml files for DB
   loading, how can I do it? since I am using only one xml file(given
   above) to load db stuff.

I am using Spring 3 framework.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`<context:property-placeholder ... />` is the XML equivalent to the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. So, prefer that. The `<util:properties/>` simply factories a java.util.Properties instance that you can inject.

In Spring 3.1 (not 3.0...) you can do something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/foo/bar/services.properties")
public class ServiceConfiguration { 

    @Autowired Environment environment; 

    @Bean public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource( ){ 
        String user = this.environment.getProperty("ds.user");
        ...
    } 
}
```

In Spring 3.0, you can "access" properties defined using the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer mechanism using the SpEl annotations:

```java
@Value("${ds.user}") private String user;
```

If you want to remove the XML all together, simply register the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer manually using Java configuration. I prefer the 3.1 approach. But, if youre using the Spring 3.0 approach (since 3.1's not GA yet...), you can now define the above XML like this:

```java
@Configuration 
public class MySpring3Configuration {     
        @Bean 
        public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() { 
             PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = ...
             ppc.setLocations(...);
             return ppc; 
        } 

        @Bean 
        public class DataSource dataSource(
                @Value("${ds.user}") String user, 
                @Value("${ds.pw}") String pw, 
                ...) { 
            DataSource ds = ...
            ds.setUser(user);
            ds.setPassword(pw);                        
            ...
            return ds;
        }
}
```

Note that the PPC is defined using a `static` bean definition method. This is required to make sure the bean is registered early, because the PPC is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` - it can influence the registration of the beans themselves in the context, so it necessarily has to be registered before everything else.

Comment: But again you will need 

@Bean 
public static PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer pspc() in Spring 3.1 example

Comment: This is the best answer. One quick note: If you use Spring >= 3.1, use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer rather than the old PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. It supports Environment and all new stuff introduced in Spring 3.1 better.

Answer (score 20):

First, you don't need to define both of those locations. Just use `classpath:config/properties/database.properties`. In a WAR, `WEB-INF/classes` is a classpath entry, so it will work just fine.

After that, I think what you mean is you want to [use Spring's schema-based configuration to create a configurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-pphc). That would go like this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/properties/database.properties"/>
```

Note that you don't need to "ignoreResourceNotFound" anymore. If you need to define the properties separately using `util:properties`:

```
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="jdbcProperties" ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
```

There's usually not any reason to define them separately, though.

Comment: 1) if i define <util:properties, is it required to use again <context:property-placeholder?  2) Since I am using Spring 3, is it required to use above xml file with bean class? Can I use annotation for loading db details?

Comment: `util:properties` only creates a bean of type `java.util.Properties`. It doesn't do placeholder replacement. The simplest way to do replacements is using `context:property-placeholder` in XML. You could create and configure your own PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer instance without XML if you wanted--using Java config, for instance--but I'm not sure anyone would consider that a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me: 
`<context:property-placeholder location="file:src/resources/spring/AppController.properties"/>`

Somehow "classpath:xxx" is not picking the file.

Comment: Your ide config included {src/resources} as one of the classpath items. So placing your file as {src/resources/spring/AppController.properties}, the classpath reference for the file would be "classpath:spring/AppController.properties".