# spring get properties difference

Tags: spring, properties

Import properties

What are the three differences?

1. Reading property files using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
2. Reading property files using [context:property-placeholder]
3. Reading properties file using [util: properties] and Spring EL

Answer (score 2):

1. `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` class pulls values from a properties file into bean definitions.
2. `<context:property-placeholder ... />` is a XML equivalent to the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.
3. `<util:properties/>` is equivalent to java.util.Properties

   Detailed information provided on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542506/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-and-contextproperty-placeholder)