# How to send a CSRF token at first request for authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, jhipster

I have an operational webapp based on JHipster. It is already token based authentification with, in addition,  CSRF hack protection.
I wrote a rest (remote) client in pure java.
So it is not an API like angular which send the token.
I need to send it when attempt to authenticate against webapp (hosted at a remote web server).
I don't find any example on how to send it.
When I authentificate against "JHisper" web app (through spring security), I got a `MissingCsrfTokenException`.

How to do ? thanks

Comment: A more global problem question to request a remote server based on jhispter for authentication : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096595/how-to-access-spring-rest-api-in-jhipster-with-spring-resttemplate